# Duda sobre reasignación a variables globales y uso de global

Tags: python, variables, variables-globales, scope

¿Por qué en la función `Results()` no tira el error de `variable referenced before assignment`?

No entiendo porque no aparece ese error puesto que se utiliza una variable que no esta declarada en la función:

```
def Results():  
    if str(operation)[-2] == "." and str(operation)[-1] == "0" :                    
        if operation == 0.0:
            clear() 
        else:
            textshow.set(int(operation))
            text.set("")                    
    elif str(operation).count("e") == 1:        
        textshow.set(("%.10E" % operation))
        text.set("")                    
    else:       
        textshow.set(round(float(operation),10))
        text.set("")
```

En cambio aquí si no declaro la variable global y si no estuviera el `try: , except:` si daría el error:

```
def operations_combinated():
    global tipo
    global operation    
    try:    
        if tipo == "Resta":                         
            operation = operation - float(text.get())                                               
        elif tipo == "Division":        
            operation = operation / float(text.get())                   
        elif tipo == "Multiplicacion":      
            operation = operation * float(text.get())                   
        elif tipo == "Suma":    
            operation = operation + float(text.get())           
        if operation == "0.0" or operation == "0":
            tipo =""
            operation =""
            text.set("")
    except:
        pass                                    
    tipo="" 
    Results()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es uno de los errores más comunes en Python referido con el ámbito de las variables.

- No hay problema alguno para acceder al objeto asociado a una variable global dentro de una función:

  ```
  x = 0

  def foo():
      y = x + 1
      print(y)
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> foo() 
  > 1
  > ```
- Si intentamos reasignar a una variable definida globalmente sin especificar que se trate la variable como global mediante `global x`, la reasignación simplemente no tiene lugar, se crea una nueva variable local, con el mismo nombre que la global y que la enmascara. Es a esa nueva variable local a la que se le asigna el nuevo objeto. La variable global queda intacta (como vemos sigue valiendo 0) y la local deja de existir nada más retornar la función.

  ```
  x = 0

  def foo():
      x = 13
      print("X dentro de foo: ", x)
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> foo() 
  > X dentro de foo: 13
  > >>> x
  > 0
  > ```
- Si especificamos la variable como global en la función y esta definida globalmente antes de llamar a la función,  al reasignar no se crea una nueva variable local, se reasigna a la global como cabe esperar.

  ```
  x = 0

  def foo():
      global x
      x = 13
      print("X dentro de foo: ", x)
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> foo() 
  > X dentro de foo: 13
  > >>> x
  > 13
  > ```
- Si intentamos reasignar a una variable global, sin declararla como tal en la función, y en la resignación intentamos usar el "valor" previo de esa variable tenemos el problema que comentas:

  ```
  x = 7

  def foo():
      x = x + 13
      print("X dentro de foo: ", x)
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> foo() 
  >
  > Exception has occurred: UnboundLocalError
  >     local variable 'bar' referenced before assignment
  > ```

  ¿Por qué pasa esto si no hay problema en leer una variable global como en el primer caso? ¿No debería simplemente crearse una variable local con el mismo nombre como en el segundo ejemplo?

  **En el mismo momento que se realiza  una asignación a una variable en cualquier parte un ámbito, Python automáticamente considera que esa variable es local al mismo y oculta cualquier variable de nombre similar en cualquier ámbito externo.** Esto ya lo hemos visto en el segundo ejemplo, solo que aquí al hacer  `x = x + 13`, antes de evaluar la parte derecha Python pasa a considerar `x` como local por lo que al intentar evaluar `x + 13` la variable `x` aún no existe porque, de hecho, la estamos creando en esta misma expresión.

  El error es muy claro de hecho, no dice que la variable no esté definida como ocurriría con:

  ```
  def foo():
      a = x + 1
  ```

  dice:

  > local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

  ---

  > Variable local 'x' referenciada antes de la asignación

  Es decir, el intérprete cuando ve:

  ```
  x = x + 13
  ```

  crea un nuevo identificador local `x` y procede a asignarle el resultado de evaluar la parte derecha de la expresión `x + 13`, pero `x` en este momento existe, pero no se le ha asignado ningún objeto todavía.
- Si declaras la variable como global dentro de la función esto no ocurre porque ya está definida en el momento de la asignación:

  ```
  x = 7

  def foo():
      global x
      x = x + 13
      print("X dentro de foo: "x)
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> foo()
  > X dentro de foo: 20
  > >>> x
  > 20
  > ```

Todo lo anterior está muy bien, pero la primera premisa que hay que tener en cuenta es que es mala práctica por lo general acceder a variables globales desde una función (otra cosa son constantes, por convención nombradas en mayúsculas) pero es peor aún si cabe modificarlas desde la función. El uso de variable globales debe restringirse al máximo por muchas razones:

- Violan la defunción pura de una función , mismo resultado para los mismos argumentos de entrada siempre.
- Causan efectos colaterales fuera de la función, lo que hace el código mucho menos legible y mucho más difícil de mantener y depurar.
- Hacen el código mucho menos reutilizable.

Si quieres modificar una variable global con una función es mucha mejor idea hacer algo así:

```
x = 13

def foo(val):
   val = val + 7
   return val

x = foo(x)
```

La reasignación se produce en el ámbito al que pertenece la variable y la función no tiene efectos colaterales implícitos.

---

---

Es muy común que ante el problema presentado en el penúltimo ejemplo a alguien se le ocurra lo siguiente:

```
x = 13

def foo():
    aux = x
    x = aux + 7
```

con la idea de que si asignamos previamente el objeto de la variable global a una variable local auxiliar, luego podemos usarla para asignar a la variable local con el mismo nombre que la global. Pues va a ser que no, en el momento que hay un intento de reasignación **en cualquier parte del ámbito** la variable pasa a ser considerada como local, por lo que en `aux = x` tenemos el mismo error, a `x` no se le ha asignado todavía nada. Parece un comportamiento algo extraño, pero tiene que ver con como Python pasa el código a bytecode y genera pasa nuestra función a un objeto en memoria:

```
x = 13

def foo():
    aux = x
    x = aux + 7
```

> ```
> >>> from dis import dis
> >>> dis(foo)
>
> 537           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
>               2 STORE_FAST               1 (aux)
>
> 538           4 LOAD_FAST                1 (aux)
>               6 LOAD_CONST               1 (7)
>               8 BINARY_ADD
>              10 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
>              12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
>              14 RETURN_VALUE
> ```

```
x = 13
def foo():
    aux = x
```

> ```
> >>> from dis import dis
> >>> dis(foo)
>
> 545           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
>               2 STORE_FAST               0 (aux)
>               4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
> ```

Las lineas interesantes de bytecode son: `0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)` en el primer ejemplo y `0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)` en el segundo. En el primer caso la primera intrucción trata de acceder al objeto asociado a una variable **local** llamada `x` (`LOAD_FAST`) mientras que en el segundo caso trata de acceder al objeto asociado a una varible **global** (`LOAD_GLOBAL`). El primer caso falla porque a `x` (variable local) no se le ha asignado referencia alguna todabía, esto ocurriría después:

> ```
>               4 LOAD_FAST                1 (aux)
>               6 LOAD_CONST               1 (7)
>               8 BINARY_ADD
>              10 STORE_FAST               0 (x) # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
> ```

¿Se puede entonces crear una variable local con el mismo nombre que una global y usar el valor de la global a la hora de asignar a la local? Pues es Python, pocas cosas no son posibles, por muy mala idea que sea... Por ejemplo:

```
x = 13

def foo():
    x = globals()["x"] + 7
    print(x)

foo()
print(x)
```

claro, que lo normal es hacer algo así:

```
x = 13

def foo(x):
    x = x + 7
    print(x)

foo(x)
print(x)
```

Por último, es importante recordar que `global x` **no define ni inicializa** una variable global, solo declara que en ese ámbito `x` es una variable que pertenece al espacio global y que si se produce una asignación debe usarse dicha variable global y no crear una variable local.

Eso es cierto, pero `global` si que permite a una función definir variables globales aunque estas no existan antes de que fuera llamada:

```
def foo():
    global x
    x = 7
    print(x)

foo()
print(x) # x existe en el espacio global porque foo la creó
```

Si lo anterior eran malas prácticas, esto ya es... Python por principio no trata al programador como estúpido y lo encorseta dirigiendolo por el camino correcto prohibiendole hacer ciertas cosas. Pero esto tiene su punto malo, no evita que el programador haga estupideces. El uso de variables globales  parece algo pueril en un ejemplo como este, pero en situaciones reales con códigos medianamente complejos es posible que termine causando problemas de salud a ti mismo o a otro desgraciado que le toque depurar tu código, si esa variable es usada en otras partes del código la simple llamada a una fucnión como esta produce efectos colaterales que se extienden más alla de ella, pudiendo causar en el mejor de los casos una excepción y en el peor resultados inesperados a los que cuesta mucho seguirles la pista.

Comment: Si hay una variable declarada fuera de cualquier funcion, y esta variable es llamada y modificada de varias funciones , se podria decir que en ese caso si es necesario usar una variable global?,  si por este comentario no entiendes la pregunta puedo modificar la pregunta y añadir el codigo correspondiente